# a term to refer to "take away part of their salary"

Tags: vocabulary

In my company, employees should work from 9:00 am to 6:00 pm, 5 days a week. My company buys employees insurance, provides stock options to employees and pay wage monthly and had never been delayed.

If an employee makes a mistake, HR will deduct/take away part of their salary, for example, being late one time will make the employee lose $100 in salary, only for that month.

Is there a term or common phrase to refer to this kind of rule?

Comment: Could this be _docking pay_? Or does that apply only to hourly wages and not lump sums of money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least informally, it's common to hear **dock their (pay / salary / wages)**.

From [*dock*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dock#h3):

> Merriam-Webster
>   **1 a** : to subject to a deduction
>   // dock someone's wages

So, you could hear something like the following:

> "That was a big mistake. I'm going to have to dock your pay."

It can refer to either a permanent reduction in salary, or to a one-time decrease, particularly in terms of people who are paid by the hour.